# Cookies not showing in the Google Application section

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, cookies

Hi I am a beginner and building a MERN app, its been 3 days i am trying to get cookies, I am able to see the cookies in the google network section which shows
set cookies: and my cookies
But when I open the application section to see cookies its completely empty i tried changing brwsers but all in vain. Kindly help me in this regard, I have not slept properly due to this error, I'll really appreciate this.
This is my Backend login code:

```
import User from "../models/user.model.js";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import createError from "../utils/createError.js";

export const register = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 5);
    const newUser = new User({
      ...req.body,
      password: hash,
    });
    await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).send("User created successfuly!");
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};

export const login = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });

    if (!user) return next(createError(404, "User not found!"));

    const isCorrect = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!isCorrect) return next(createError(400, "Wrong password or username"));

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: user._id,
        isSeller: user.isSeller,
      },
      process.env.JWT_KEY,{expiresIn:"1h"}
    );

    const { password, ...info } = user._doc;

    res
      .cookie("accessToken", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "none", 
        secure: true,         
      })
      .status(200)
      .send(info); //new line
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};

export const logout = async (req, res, next) => {
  res
    .clearCookie("accessToken", {
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true,
    })
    .status(200)
    .send("User has been logged out!");
};
```

This is my Front end Login code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./Login.scss";
import axios from "axios";

const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login",
        {
          username,
          password,
        },
        { withCredentials: true }
      );
      console.log(res.data);
      console.log(res.headers);
      console.log(document.cookie);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err);
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="login">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h1>Sign in</h1>
        <label htmlFor="">Username</label>
        <input
          name="username"
          type="text"
          placeholder="johndoe"
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
        />

        <label htmlFor="">Password</label>
        <input
          name="password"
          type="password"
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        {error && error.message}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

This is my server.js

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import userRoute from "./routes/user.route.js";
import authRoute from "./routes/auth.route.js";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cors from "cors"

const app = express();

//Some endpoints to remove eror || MiddleWares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({
  origin:"http://127.0.0.1:5173",
  credentials:true,
  exposedHeaders: ['set-cookie'],// new line added
}))


dotenv.config();

const connect = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO);
    console.log("Connected to mongoDB!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

//Routes Use
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const errorStatus = err.status || 500;
  const errMessage = err.message || "Something went wrong"

  return res.status(errorStatus).send(errMessage)
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  connect();
  console.log("Backend server Js runing...");
});
```

This is the Network Tab image
[image: Network Tab Image]

This is Application Tab Image
[image: This is application tab image]

Token name is accessToken which is showing in Network tab but not in he application cookie tab

Comment: Can you show the Network tab of what you have did on your frontend side?

Comment: Yes, I can send you Network tab, application tab, my front end login, backend login, and server.js file

Comment: but there is not enough space to send code also it dont allow to send image in comment how should i send?

Comment: HI @SyedUsmanHassan, you can modify your original question to includes them

Comment: ok I have included them, please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might happen because Chrome only allows localhost with `httpOnly: true` set in cookies.
So in your origin, you need to change the origin from 127.0.0.1  to  localhost as:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin:"http://localhost:5173",
  credentials:true,
  exposedHeaders: ['set-cookie'],// new line added
}))
```

Also if you are using Vite instead of CRA (Create React App ):
as Vite uses  127.0.0.1   instead of   localhost, then you need to change the vite config file as ( so that Vite uses localhost )

```
import { defineConfig} from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import dns from 'dns'

dns.setDefaultResultOrder('verbatim')


export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    server: {
        host: "localhost",
        port: "5173",
    },
});
```

I hope you have solved your problem .